# Let {$a_k$} and {$b_k$} be sequences. Suppose that $|b_{k+1}-b_k| \leq a_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let {$a_k$} and {$b_k$} be sequences. Suppose that $|b_{k+1}-b_k| \leq a_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges. Prove that {$b_k$} converges.

I know I need to prove by showing that {$b_k$} is Cauchy, but I'm not sure if I can use {$a_k$} is Cauchy since it converges (because it only says the sum of {$a_k$} converges).

Can anyone show me a formal proof of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By definition, there exists $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k=n}^m a_k < \epsilon$,(Since $a_k$ is nonnegative) so
$$ |b_m - b_n| = \left|\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} (b_{k+1} - b_k)\right|
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} |b_{k+1} - b_k| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} a_k < \epsilon
$$

Comment: are you trying to show that $\sum_{k=0}^n b_k$ converges? Because I mean to show that the sequence {$b_k$} converges, aren't they two different things?

Comment: You need to consider that $b_k$ may be negative don't you?

Comment: @mathmathmath If the sum converges then the sequence $\to 0$.

Comment: @Chilango Then repeat the proof for $-b_k$.

Comment: @HenryW. I am required to prove by showing {$b_k$} is Cauchy, can you show me that way?

Comment: yes but you need to say it.

Comment: @mathmathmath Is this OK?

Comment: @HenryW. That's great! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, very nice!